# MySQL-PHP display data separately in html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display data from a MySQL table using PHP inside html page, wrapping data in HTML table.

I have 11 columns in a MySQL table and *x* rows, among which i need just 6 columns for all rows to get printed as HTML table. Which i am able to do.(Successfully)

**My Approach:**

```html
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT order_id, order_name, order_from, order_to, order_pickup, order_dropoff FROM users");

// Printing results in HTML
echo "\n";
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr id='$line[order_id]'>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "\n";
```

**Output:**

[image]

**My Issue:**
Among these 6 columns i want 1 column named `order_id` to be the `id` of the row (`tr`), so now i want only remaining five as *table-cell's* `td's`. I don't want the value of `order_id` column as table cell.

Comment: Then don't echo it? I advice using `if`

Comment: divy3993, please check my answer too, just to see if It works as expected. Else there is not need and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @Naruto check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check also a column name in a `$line`:

```
foreach ($line as $col_name => $col_value) {
    if ($col_name != 'order_id') {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `=>` does here?

Comment: `=>` indicates key-value syntax for a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 2):

Ok there are a number of solutions to this. Generally when writing this kind of code one often separates the database layer from the template layer and asses the information to the template layer.

For the sake of your example you can choose to remove the foreach and individually define the separate column values which in my opinion is usually the best way to go as you already know all the columns and have more control in when to echo them:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT order_id, order_name, order_from, order_to, order_pickup, order_dropoff FROM users");

// Printing results in HTML
echo "\n";

while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr id='$line[order_id]'>\n";

    echo "\t\t<td>$line['title']</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td>$line['second title']</td>\n";

    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}

echo "\n";
```

Another approach as I believe a user already mentioned is to use an if
statement. You can do this on the key of the array:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT order_id, order_name, order_from, order_to, order_pickup, order_dropoff FROM users");

// Printing results in HTML
echo "\n";

while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr id='$line[order_id]'>\n";

    foreach ($line as $col_name => $col_value) {
        if ($col_name === 'order_id') {
            continue;
        }
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }

    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}

echo "\n";
```

Comment: Yes your solution is helpful too since i know about my column names. Thank You Very Much!

Comment: Good to be of service, I have read some of the other comments and I think you are still trying to figure out how things work in PHP. There is this great site which can help you called [link][https://www.codecademy.com]. This should explain most of the basics including most of the syntax such as => in a foreach

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is simple, you just need to check if the array key is order_id, if it is, then don't echo it :D

```
echo "\n";
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    echo "\t<tr id='$line[order_id]'>\n";
    foreach ($line as $key => $col_value) {
        if ($key != 'order_id')
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "\n";
```

Comment: You got me wrong, i want the order_id as id of the respective `tr`(which i am able to achieve sucessfull, which you removed here) but not to be printed as the `td` "Table-cell".

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a better answer from what I will post, but I will post it just to see how simple is the idea.

The disadvantage with my code is that it checks the `if()` in each loop statement increasing the complexity of your code.

Basically you set a `bool` variable to hold the first pass of each table row. This variable is set to false (`$pass_one = false`). Then when we start to getting the columns info we set the bool variable to `true` and skip the first element. In the next column iterates, we proceed as we should. After we've done with the column set, we change the `$pass_one` back to false and proceed to the other rows repeatedly.

```
<?php $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT order_id, order_name, order_from, order_to, order_pickup, order_dropoff FROM users");

$pass_one = false; //you set it  to false

// Printing results in HTML
echo "\n";
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr id='$line[order_id]'>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        if (!$pass_one) { 
            $pass_one = true; // you pass the first echo, so you set the bool to true
            continue; // skip the first pass, (this statement goes to foreach() loop
        }
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
    $pass_one = false; // we get a new <tr> so we set the $pass_one for that loop to false
}
echo "\n";

?>
```